# What is meant by streaming task paused, reason error (-5)?

Tags: video, gstreamer

I used this pipeline,

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc pattern="snow" ! video/x-raw, framerate=10/1, width=200, height=150 ! videomixer name=mix ! autovideosink videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, framerate=10/1, width=640, height=360 ! mix.
```

But, After Closing the output window,

```
EOS on shutdown enabled -- waiting for EOS after Error
Waiting for EOS...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc1: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2946): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc1:
streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2946): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
```

What does that means, and what is this **streaming task paused, reason error (-5)** error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipeline works for me.. but you have to close it with Ctrl+C not by closing the window.. Its because there is not implemented proper handling of closing window (maybe there is flag for that somewhere to autovideosink or other video sink.. I dont know).

The problem rises with even this simple pipe (you could try with glimagesink and xvimagesink but the error is similar):

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc pattern="snow" ! ximagesink
```

When checking docs for [the error](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstPad.html#GstFlowReturn):

> GST_FLOW_ERROR
>   Some (fatal) error occurred. Element generating this error should post an error message with more details.

Well we examine the problem with higher debug logs (you should already learnt this lesson though!) we see:

> 0:00:02.697769439 29872      0x2647590 WARN              ximagesink ximagesink.c:1423:gst_x_image_sink_show_frame: could not output image - no window
>
> 0:00:02.697815511 29872      0x2647590 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2943:gst_base_src_loop: error:
>
> Internal data flow error.
>
> 0:00:02.697826432 29872      0x2647590 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2943:gst_base_src_loop: error: streaming task paused, reason error (-5)

Well the error is obvious:

```
could not output image - no window
```

Btw the error codes are:

```
typedef enum {
  /* custom success starts here */
  GST_FLOW_CUSTOM_SUCCESS_2 = 102,
  GST_FLOW_CUSTOM_SUCCESS_1 = 101,
  GST_FLOW_CUSTOM_SUCCESS = 100,

  /* core predefined */
  GST_FLOW_OK             =  0,
  /* expected failures */
  GST_FLOW_NOT_LINKED     = -1,
  GST_FLOW_FLUSHING       = -2,
  /* error cases */
  GST_FLOW_EOS            = -3,
  GST_FLOW_NOT_NEGOTIATED = -4,
  GST_FLOW_ERROR          = -5,
  GST_FLOW_NOT_SUPPORTED  = -6,

  /* custom error starts here */
  GST_FLOW_CUSTOM_ERROR   = -100,
  GST_FLOW_CUSTOM_ERROR_1 = -101,
  GST_FLOW_CUSTOM_ERROR_2 = -102
} GstFlowReturn;
```

So again - the solution is to stop it with Ctrl+C instead of hitting window cross.. If this is unaceptable then you will have to implement it in C with proper handling of windows closing (I would swear that there was tutorial for it in gstreamer docs..)

Answer (score 0):

I got this result when the user hit the system process limit.
ulimit -u    can show the user's limit
pstree     shows the processes for the user
/etc/security/limits.conf   configures limits

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).